# Checking "Client-only Framework subset" in C# project properties have no effect (VS2008), is this normal?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-client-profile

I wanted to try to deploy our project for .net 3.5 client framework (so that we could distribute it with smaller runtime), but when I go to VS 2008 Project properties and check the “Client-only Framework subset” checkbox (and click Save all), it has no effect - the .csproj file does not change (the diff for whole project is empty), and when I open the project proeprties next time, the checkbox is unxecked again.

Do I have to install some VS hotfix, or does this really work just in VS2010? I hoped that after checking this, the compiler would warn me when I use a library that is not included in client subset of .NET.

The project type is C# .net 3.5 wpf application.

Comment: Per the VS compat team, WPF Applications, by default, already target the client-only subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried enabling the Client-only Framework subset option in a brand new WPF Application project in VS 2008 SP1 (9.0.30729.1 SP). It caused `<TargetFrameworkSubset>Client</TargetFrameworkSubset>` to be added to the first `<PropertyGroup>` in the .csproj file. Unchecking the option again changed the value from `Client` to `Full`.

With the option enabled, I get warnings about references to assemblies that are not available in the Client subset:

> Could not resolve assembly "System.Web,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>   processorArchitecture=x86". The
>   assembly is not listed as part of the
>   "Client" TargetFrameworkSubset.

Comment: Thnaks - in that case something is wrong with my setup - I get this exact line when I select Client subset as target in VS 2010, but in VS 2008 SP1 nothing happens. I use several VS plugins, so I'll look into them. Thanks for your time!